# How To Choose a Better RAM

Tags: memory, bios

My laptop came with 2gb RAM but i am thinking to extend it to 6 GB By keeping 4gb ram in The Other slot. Is it better to take 4gb RAM and extend ny system memory To 6GB or Take 2GB RAM and extend it to 4GB .Please give me reply as soon as possible. Thanks in advance

Comment: Your question is, is it better to have 4 or 6 GB of RAM?

Comment: Why are you choosing to stick with 6G instead of just going of 8GB?  [We have had questions similar to this in the past](http://superuser.com/questions/144130/is-1gb-1gb-ram-better-than-2gb-0-5gb?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

First you need to find out the type of ram you will need. A good tool for this purpose can be found [here](http://www.crucial.com/). Then you'll need to do some research on an online market (Such as NewEgg or BestBuy) and see what fits your budget. Then you need to choose what will you NEED. If your laptop is really only used for school, work, regular internet browsing, media streaming, light gaming, or other simple tasks, you really don't need more then 4gb ram. If you want to do a bit more resource intensive tasks, such as video editing, gaming, or running other programs that simply requite more ram, then 6gb will be better for you.

In the end, it all comes down to what programs you'll be using. You'll have to do some research on system requirements for programs/games you'll be running. System requirements for games can be found on steam, [SystemRequirementsLab](http://www.systemrequirementslab.com/cyri), or simply by performing a simple google search for "*program name here* system requirements".

Answer (score -1):

If your laptop comes with a 32bit. Then the max you can install is 4gb. If it's 64bit, then 6gb would be the recommended upgrade if you have the option.

Comment: This is not generally true. See PAE. However, 32-bit versions of Windows are generally restricted to 4 GB.

Comment: That's why I said if it's 32bit then normally 4gb the max restriction.

Comment: Yeah, but that only applies in some circumstances. I've used more than 4 GB with 32-bit versions of Linux, for example.

Comment: That would work. I suppose depends on what OS the user has installed